# solutions for running & sharing jupyter notebooks in Azure

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am looking for a way to create and share jupyter notebooks in Azure, similar to kaggle.

The default https://notebooks.azure.com/ only allows to keept it private, or share with everyone.
However I would need to be able to add collaborators.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to directly collaborate within Azure. You can use github to let other users collaborate and then import the project into azure notebook.

Answer (score 0):

One of the almost custom solution could be the usage of [Azure Data Science Virtual Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/is-is/services/virtual-machines/data-science-virtual-machines/).

You can create the VM connect to it with RDP or SSH and share the access to VM with you collaborators, create separated VMs for them.

Not really a SaaS but could be a solution if you need to access or keep the data in Azure.